# Invoice record adding in netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I have an issue.
Please help me when I add the invoice in NetSuite it's given me a
error:[code] => USER_ERROR [message] => Please enter value(s) for: Department, Class, Warehouse
Can any one tell me how can generate NetSuite invoice via API.

```
$inv=new Invoice();

$customFormR=new RecordRef();
$customFormR->internalId =104;





//'1 Aquatic Fitness Concepts'

$inv_items= new InvoiceItem();

$itemRR = new RecordRef();
$itemRR->internalId = 25;
$itemRR->recordType = "inventoryItem";
$inv_items->item=$itemRR;

$location=new RecordRef();
$location->internalId =2;

$inv_items->location=$location;

$departmentRR=new RecordRef();
$departmentRR->internalId =6;
$inv_items->department=$departmentRR;

$classRR=new RecordRef();
$classRR->internalId =22;

$inv_items->class=$classRR;

$inv_it_list=new InvoiceItemList();

$inv_it_list->item=array($inv_items);
$inv->itemList= $inv_it_list;
$inv->entity = new RecordRef();
$inv->entity->internalId = 932;
//$inv->entity
$inv->customForm=$customFormR;

$request = new AddRequest();
$request->record = $inv;


$addResponse = $service->add($request);

if (!$addResponse->writeResponse->status->isSuccess) {
    echo "ADD ERROR";
    print_r($addResponse);
    exit();
} else {
    echo "ADD SUCCESS, id " . $addResponse->writeResponse->baseRef->internalId;
}
```

Comment: I am using PHPTookkit Code

Comment: Post your code. I'll tell you where you've done something wrong and provide the solution.

Comment: You need to post your code, please.

Comment: Thanks Danilo, Check what i am doing wrong..

Comment: If you have a code for creating invoice in netsuite please send me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NetSuite, you have the option of setting Location, Department, Class at the header level as a default, and on the line level as an override of the default.

Take a look at how Location, Department, Class are set up for transactions in your NetSuite account. Your code shows you are trying to set these fields at the line item level. If the option to specify them on the line level is not enabled (Setup->Accounting->Accounting Preferences->General), you should not be able to set them on the line level.

Try setting those fields on the header level. For example:

```
$inv->department = $departmentRR;
```